# isc-dhcp-server configuration - Assign multiple IP addresses to one MAC

Tags: dhcp

Right now I am doing the following to allocate an IP address to a specific MAC.

```
  host 1 {hardware ethernet 02:00:00:ef:0d:20;fixed-address 17x.31.xxx.2xx;option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;option routers 51.xxx.xx.254;}
```

How can I modify this so I can use multiple IP address for the MAC `02:00:00:ef:0d:20` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just adding , after each IP seemed to work.

```
host 1 {hardware ethernet 02:00:00:ef:0d:20;fixed-address IP1, IP2, IP3, IP4;option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;option routers 51.xxx.xx.254;}
```